# Can the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)-1$ be factored into the product of two polynomials with integers coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $a,b,c$ distinct integers. Can the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)-1$
>   be factored into the product of two polynomials with integers
>   coefficients?

I think the answer is no. Should I use the Cardano formulas and x(x-1)(x+1)-1 to prove it? Is anyone have an idea?

Comment: $(x-a)^3-1=(-a+x-1) (a^2-2 a x-a+x^2+x+1)$

Comment: @Baconaro But $a=b=c$ is not allowed, see the assumptions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde guess i dont know how to read :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must factor as: $(x-r)(x^2+mx+n)$ where $r,m,n$ are integers. In other words, the polynomial must have an integer root: $(r-a)(r-b)(r-c)=1$. This is only possible if each factor is $1$ or $-1$. But then two of the factors will be the same, so two of $a,b,c$ will be the same, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, and your counterexample is good enough:

$$x(x-1)(x+1)-1=x^3-x-1$$

If this can be factored, then one of the factors must be linear of the form $x+c$, where the integer $c$ divides $1$, so either $x-1$ or $x+1$. But neither $1$ nor $-1$ is a root of the polynomial.

Comment: Is there **any** example with distinct $a,b,c$ which factors ?

Comment: No, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I think that the answer should show that there is *no* such example at all. That $x^3-x-1$ does not factor, is just one example.

Comment: In my opinion, "Not in general [...]" is a full answer to the above question. If you want to include all cases, then the question should be "Do there exist distinct integers a, b, c such that the following polynomial factors as [...]"